# Suppressing indentation of the next paragraph

Tags: environments, indentation

I'm trying to define an environment/command, with the following property: The immediate paragraph after the environment must not be indented. The following shows my attempt at defining such environment/command:

```
\makeatletter    
\newenvironment{NoIndEnv}{}{\par\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}    
\newcommand{\NoIndCmd}[1]{#1 \par\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}    
\makeatother
```

Now compare the following two:

```
\begin{NoIndEnv}
   Text ...
\end{NoIndEnv}

Some text ...
```

and

```
\NoIndCmd{Text ...}

Some text ...
```

For some reason, the environment definition works only if it is placed after a `\section` command; i.e.:

```
\section{}

\begin{NoIndEnv}
   Text ...
\end{NoIndEnv}

Some text ...
```

Could you please help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Simply ending it with `\par\noindent` doesn't work?

Comment: @Martin: Peculiarly, it does not work either!

Comment: Even for commands,`\par\noindent` can only work if there's no empty line (that means `\par`) afterward.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading` are done inside a group, in the environment case. Solution: do them after the group has ended.

```
\newenvironment{NoIndEnv}
  {}
  {\par\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading}
```

Comment: Thank you both for the question, and the answer: it is very useful and not that easy to find!