# LyX: Inhibit indentation after quote

Tags: lyx, indentation, quoting

Is it possible with LyX and without having to use ERT everytime to inhibit indentation in standard text *after* (short) block quotes? ([similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111780/inhibit-indentation-in-paragraph-after-using-the-quoting-package)) When the quote environment is using a spacing environment, LyX adds a blank line and thus starts a new paragraph.
I redefined the environment like this:

```
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}
{\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}\begin{spacing}{1.2}\oldquote}
{\oldendquote\end{spacing}\vspace{\dimexpr-12pt-\topsep+\baselineskip\relax}}
```

When I use the following in the preamble, the indent after the quote becomes much smaller, but there is still one:

```
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}
{\begin{spacing}{1.2}\oldquote}
{\oldendquote\end{spacing}\noindent}
```

Is it possible to adjust this in the preamble in order to remove the indent after every quotation?

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/suppressing-indentation-of-the-next-paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `noindentafter` package. `\NoIndentAfterEnv{quote}` should lead to the requested behaviour.

Comment: This does not work in my case, maybe because of the adjustments in the preamble?

Comment: Where do you add `\NoIndentAfterEnv{quote}`? Before or after your adjustments? I guess it should work if you put it after your renewed definition of the `quote`-environment, but I can't test here...

Comment: Also: Have you seen this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/suppressing-indentation-of-the-next-paragraph Adding `\par\aftergroup\@afterindentfalse\aftergroup\@afterheading` to your new definition could help...

Comment: That does indeed lead to the desired behaviour. I don't really understand this code, does it also affect other parts?

Comment: It shouldn't. This is basically how LaTeX suppresses indentation after heading, and it should only affect the next paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

By default, LyX do not indent any extra black line (i.e, `\par`) after the quote, and do not indent the following text. Is you which force this, quoting inside a `spacing` environment.

So yo have at least three options:

1) Keep it simple. Remove all that code of the preamble.

2) Put `spacing` nested inside `quote`, not at the inverse.

3) Do not use the `spacing` environment. If you want quotes with a different interline space but without too much  vertical spacing after, maybe is enough for you change the `\baselineskip`, like here:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{book}
\let\oldquote\quote
\let\oldendquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}{%
\oldquote\baselineskip14pt%
}{%
\oldendquote}

\begin{document}
Bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah 
bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah
bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah:
\begin{quote}
Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. 

Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. Foo foo foo. 
\end{quote}
Bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah 
bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah
bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah bah:
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another simple way could be some like `\def\quote{\list{}{\rightmargin100pt\leftmargin50pt\topsep0pt}\item[]\baselineskip20pt}`.

Comment: You are right, without my preamble LyX does not indent the text after blockquotes. However, I want them to have a smaller line spacing. In your example I can hardly see a difference. The third option works fine, but just for clarification, could you give me the code for the second option? This way I can control the spacing with the same unit as the main text.

Comment: @johnny7 Point 2 is only redefine the environment as   `\begin{quote}\begin{spacing} ... \end{spacing}\end{quote}`  instead of `\begin{spacing}..\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}\end{spacing}` (what you've actually triedt). But `quote` is really a hidden list,  nearly defined as in my above comment. So first learn to [make your own lists](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/lyx/ownlists.htm) and maybe you will not need  fix it   with `\vspace` or similar tricks.